# UICollectioView issues with reuse cell and scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uicollectionview

I'm loading custom cells into **UICollectionView**,and on every **CELL1** i have a download button and the **progressview**,but when i started downloading something after hitting cell1 button.Upon started downloading i am updating the progressview,which shows the correct result.But while progressview is ON(when downloading is happening),when i scroll down i am seeing a progressview on **CELL5**,again if i play with it by scrolling up and down i am able to see the progressview at **CELL6**...What am i doing wrong here?...

My code goes here:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    cell.labelTitle.text = [_editionNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.labelIssue.text = [[[_editionDescriptionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                             stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "]
                            stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    cell.issueButton.tag=indexPath.row;

    [cell.issueButton setTitle:@"Download" forState:UIControlStateNormal];//once the download is completed set the title as Read.
      [cell.issueButton addTarget:self action:@selector(downloadTheIssue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    cell.tag=indexPath.row;
}
```

On receiving the data,i am updating the progressview,

```
- (void)downloadManager:(DownloadManager *)downloadManager downloadDidReceiveData:(Download *)download
{

 [self updateProgressViewForIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:download.tag inSection:0] download:download];

}

- (void)updateProgressViewForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath download:(Download *)download
{

    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // if the cell is not visible, we can return

    if (!cell)
        return;
    cell.progressView.hidden=NO;
    if (download.expectedContentLength >= 0)
    {
        // if the server was able to tell us the length of the file, then update progress view appropriately
        // to reflect what % of the file has been downloaded

        cell.progressView.progress = (double) download.progressContentLength / (double) download.expectedContentLength;
    }
    else
    {
        // if the server was unable to tell us the length of the file, we'll change the progress view, but
        // it will just spin around and around, not really telling us the progress of the complete download,
        // but at least we get some progress update as bytes are downloaded.
        //
        // This progress view will just be what % of the current megabyte has been downloaded

        cell.progressView.progress = (double) (download.progressContentLength % 1000000L) / 1000000.0;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

```
#import "MyCell.h"

@implementation MyCell


- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.backgroundView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gridbg.png"]];
    self.labelTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.18f green:0.20f blue:0.23f alpha:1.00f];
    self.labelTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.labelIssue.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.00f green:0.25f blue:0.55f alpha:1.00f];
    self.labelIssue.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

}
```

Any solution would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Could you Copy/Paste your MyCell.m class ? I'm getting the felling the problem comes from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually should store progress for each item somewhere, because when cell is reused, it will be lost and never restored. For example, make a `NSMutableArray *_downloadProgressArray` for that and adjust your methods accordingly:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.labelTitle.text = [_editionNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.labelIssue.text = [[[_editionDescriptionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                         stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "]
                        stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSNumber* progress = [_downloadProgressArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (progress == nil) {
        // download not started
        cell.issueButton.hidden = NO;
        cell.issueButton.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell.issueButton setTitle:@"Download" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //once the download is completed set the title as Read.
        [cell.issueButton addTarget:self action:@selector(downloadTheIssue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.progressView.hidden = YES;
    } else {
        cell.issueButton.hidden = YES;
        cell.progressView.hidden = NO;
        cell.progressView.progress = progress.doubleValue;
    }

    cell.tag = indexPath.row;
    return cell;
}


- (void)downloadManager:(DownloadManager *)downloadManager downloadDidReceiveData:(Download *)download
{
    _downloadProgressArray[download.tag] = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(your progress here)];
    [self updateProgressViewForIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:download.tag inSection:0] download:download];
}
```

And don't forget to set `nil` when download is completed.

Answer (score 0):

as you said you are reusing the cells then you have to reset the values to default since the progress bar value is changed and the cell is reused somewhere else.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.progressView.progress = 0;
....
```

other labels are getting updated values `cell.labelIssue.text` so that is fine except for progressView value.

Comment: You mean when i start downloading something on cell1,and meanwhile when i scroll down i have to make progressview.value=0? then when i scroll back,how about my old cell1's downloading progressview?it will be gone again right?

Comment: yes in the above you have to reset the value to zero because the cell is used for another entry which might (not) have download in progress. the cell with download in progress should only update its own cell and some other cell which previously was used.